Exact definition of divergence. Is it really the dot product of nabla operator with a vector?
I was trying to understand the derivation for divergence in cylindrical and spherical coordinate system, and I am a bit confused here.

https://www.gradplus.pro/deriving-divergence-in-cylindrical-and-spherical/
Why is it "not the simple dot product"? Isn't that how we define divergence?

I would imagine that the lines following the last part of the screen grab answers the question.

They probably want to caution you to not take the derivative of the unit vectors (e.g. we don't want to include $\partial \vec{a}_i/\partial j$)

@QuantumMechanic I think it's the other way around.  They're pointing out that you do need to include the derivatives of the unit vectors, because they depend on position. Otherwise, it is a simple dot product. Or at least, the derivatives need to act on the unit vectors to the right (and not on the ones to the left).

Don't use images for Math. Instead, type the relevant passage. Also, give a reference.

Divergence of a vector field is the quantity that makes Gauss' theorem work, regardless in which coordinates we calculate the integrals. The chain rule lurks behind all the transformations. For spherical it is done here.

We physicists are very cavalier with how we work with mathematics. If you ask the mathematicians, they would not be defining divergence the way we do. It is not a simple dot product; we simply use this because it is a cheap heuristic way to remember what it is in Cartesian coördinates. It is not so in other coördinates.

The dot product here is just an abuse of notation. The nabla is an operator and is not a vector itself. The dot in this case does not mean the inner product $V\times V \to k$. It is just a notation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Definition The definition given here is coordinate-independent and will help you understand the physical significance of divergence, rather than how to calculate it. This is what Kurt G. meant by “Divergence of a vector field is the quantity that makes Gauss' theorem work.”

I believe the text is saying "don't just multiply the components as you would for a Cartesian dot product."
In cylindrical and spherical coordinates, the unit vectors $\vec a_\rho~~\vec a_\theta$, etc are not constant with position, but are themselves functions of $\rho,~\theta,~z$.  So the derivative applies to them as well.
You would essentially need to write out the metric tensor of the curved cylindrical or spherical coordinate system and do the component-wise divergence operation in tensor notation to get the most purist, correct derivation.  But this is not necessary for what you are studying, and remembering or looking up the formulas for divergence in those coordinates is sufficient.
